# Registration confusion with autofac and console app

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm trying to use autofac for dependency injection in my console app.  I'm running into issues where autofac can't find constructors for certain interfaces/classes.

Here is my latest example:

**IRepository:**

```
public interface IRepository<Planetary>
{
    IEnumerable<Planetary> Get();
}
```

**IPlanetaryRepository:**

```
public interface IPlanetaryRepository : IRepository<Planetary>
{
    IQueryable<Planetary> GetPlanetary(SystemProbe user);
}
```

**PlanetaryService:**

```
public interface IPlanetaryService
{
    Task<Planetary> Clone(Planetary source);
}

public sealed class PlanetaryService : IPlanetaryService
{
    private IPlanetaryRepository Repo { get; }

    public PlanetaryService(IPlanetaryRepository repo)
    {
        Repo = repo;
    }
}
```

**Scheduler:**

```
public class Scheduler
{
    private static IContainer Container { get; set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<PlanetaryService>().As<PlanetaryService>();
        builder.RegisterType<IPlanetaryRepository>().As<IPlanetaryRepository>();

        Container = builder.Build();

        GenerateSchedules();
    }

    public static void GenerateSchedules()
    {
        using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {

            var repo = scope.Resolve<PlanetaryService>();    <-- line where exception is thrown
        }
    }
}
```

> No constructors on type 'IPlanetaryRepository' can be found with the
>   constructor finder
>   'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'.

If I take out IPlanetaryRepository, I get this exception:

> Cannot resolve parameter IPlanetaryRepository repo of constructor...

So I'm not really sure what to do.  'PlanetaryService' needs 'IPlanetaryRepository' as a parameter, but IPlanetaryRepository doesn't have a constructor.

Is there a way to rectify this?

Comment: shouldn't you be doing this `builder.RegisterType<type>().As<Itype>();`

Comment: You don't have an implementation of IPlanetaryRepository anywhere. Write one, and then register it with AutoFac.

Comment: @RichardIrons Would it be enough to have a class that inherits IPlanetaryRepository? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don'y have any classes that implement IPlanetaryRepository so it can't find the constructor.